# Cordova Inapp Purchase iOS 8

Tags: xcode, ios8, in-app-billing, cordova-plugins

After including the iOS In App Purchase plugin, I am now getting the follow compilation error on X-code 6:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProduct", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_SKProduct_$_LocalizedPrice in SKProduct+LocalizedPrice.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is this a problem with the plugin on iOS 8 or is it a config problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the Xcode project was missing the libraries for IAP. Adding them fixed the issue and it now compiles fine.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to link the library manually. This is a Cordova bug that sometimes fails doing it automatically.

Just in casa this happens, follows this steps:

1. Go to the Build Phases tab in your project target
2. Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries" list.
3. Click the plus button at the button
4. Search for StoreKit and add the StoreKit.framework item.[image]

[image]